# Can I safely run command-line apps in single-user mode?

Tags: macos, terminal

Obviously `fsck` is pretty safe to run in single-user mode. I'm using [gtypist](http://www.gnu.org/software/gtypist/) to learn touch typing and would like to be able to run it in single user mode so that I don't have to load the whole OS just for a command-line app.

When I first try running `gtypist` I got a segmentation error 11, which "means that the program accessed a memory location that was not assigned". On subsequent attempt get "HOME environment variable not set."

I thought maybe I need to use `su` to login in as a regular user, but my user account isn't listed in `/etc/passwd`. Should it be?

Is it even "safe" to run applications in single user mode? If so - would I create a new user? Create an environment variable in the root account? I don't even see `HOME` listed as a [gtypist env variable](http://www.hep.by/gnu/gtypist/gtypist_19.html) so maybe it's not a gtypist variable at all.

On side note, just [learned](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20010406122933611) that rather than reboot into single user mode one can just open terminal and `sudo shutdown now`, after which OS X will "quietly and consistently shutdown to single-user mode." Sweet.

EDIT:
I think [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/159428/is-there-a-native-terminal-in-os-x-without-having-to-load-the-desktop-window-m/159468#159468) and the suggestion to use ">console" may be a more succinct way of addressing and answering my question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there console mode in Mac OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2443/is-there-console-mode-in-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TL;DR: Yes, you can run command line tools in Single User Mode. But not *all* command line tools. That's not what Single User Mode is meant for.

> I don't have to load the whole OS just for a command-line app.

Except, as you're discovering, you probably do.

Single user mode is meant for trouble shooting problems with the computer. It is the bare minimum needed for Darwin, the underlying Free BSD port that OS X is based on top of, to function. What you are placed in is a shell capable of running when things on the hardware are dire. It is a not a fully-functioning shell.

While it's "safe" to run applications in Single User Mode, in so much as you can't *hurt* things by running something like `gtypist`, it isn't recommended because it isn't an environment meant for running things other than emergency tools.

You should consider running a Terminal or [iTerm2](http://iterm2.com/) window in full screen mode if you'd like a monitor that's 100% terminal and running `gtypist` from there. You're not gaining anything dropping OS X to single user mode, in fact you're losing a great many things and fighting battles that don't need to be fought.

You could use [>console login](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/159428/is-there-a-native-terminal-in-os-x-without-having-to-load-the-desktop-window-m/159468#159468), but if it's simply speed of access you're looking for, the hardware and software are designed to simply be [put to sleep between uses](http://osxdaily.com/2012/04/10/shutdown-sleep-or-leave-mac-turned-on/), from which awakening is faster than rebooting into SUM anyway.

Comment: thanks for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Too_long;_didn%27t_read. hadn't come across that one.

Comment: it's not actually that I'm looking for full screen - just a faster start-up.

Comment: @MikeiLL You could also use the [>console login](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/159468/24324)

Comment: @BartArondson - yes - I think the question you linked to is probaby what I should have asked in the first place.

Comment: @MikeiLL why shut down at all? Put your computer to sleep and the wake time will beat the boot-to-SUM time.

Comment: @IanC. Sometimes I unplug from outlet, leaving on battery and just put to sleep, but wonder if that's (a very ugly-American) waste of electricity. Or if it puts more wear on the hardware.

Comment: It's not more wear than booting it. Just close the lid, let it go to sleep and don't worry about it so much. The hardware and software were all built to make this an optimal experience.

Comment: Leaving it on for days at a time? Maybe it's my Irish New-England up-bringing but that seems wrong. I love the idea of not worrying about it : )

Comment: Yes, it's fine. My iMac is regularly "on" for months at a time. It's going on 8 years old. And our MacBook Pros only ever gets slept by shutting their lids. The OS will go through stages of powering things down and eventually sleeping the entire machine as it detects you're not using it. It's certainly more correct to use your Mac this way than it is to log in to the `console`.

Comment: Wonderful. I'll add this link which includes a little more discussion for any other interested peops who come across: http://osxdaily.com/2012/04/10/shutdown-sleep-or-leave-mac-turned-on/

Comment: Single user mode *can* be dangerous to use if you aren't careful. It's no more dangerous than any other root shell, but it is a root shell, so you need to watch what you're doing.